# Is it possible to replace </sys:String> with sed command?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have been trying to replace  with  using this command       `sed 's/</sys:String>/ /'` but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 4):

either escape `/` with `\`

```
sed 's/<\/sys:String>/ /'
```

or use another separator (here comma : `,` )

```
sed 's,</sys:String>, ,'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can escape `/` with `\`:

```
sed 's/<\/sys:String>/ /'
```

Alternative to this is to use another separator. I like `|` instead of `/`. It looks good:

```
sed 's|</sys:String>| |'
```

Comment: OMG! That looks so much easier to understand when you used | . Thanks so much :)

Comment: It is pretty nice looking, yes :-) No problem.

Comment: it's nice looking until you need to use `|` inside your regular expression, and then it gets ugly.  IMO `|` should be avoided as separator because it has a special meaning (or) inside regexps, same as it's a good idea to avoid characters known to be or likely to be inside the search pattern.  It's a bad habit that should be avoided no matter how pretty it looks in the very simplest of cases.

Comment: it's used all the time, it's the OR operator.  'a|b|c' is 'a or b or c' except a,b,c,etc can be a lot more complicated than single characters.  BTW, unlike `|` or `+`, `=` has no special meaning in a regexp, it's just a character.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `/` in `/sys` with a `\` character.

Try:

```
sed 's/<\/sys:String>/ /'
```

alternatively, use something other than `/` as the separator character for the sed `s` command.  For example:

```
sed 's=</sys:String>= ='
```

I've used `=` here.  At first I was going to use `:` but then I noticed that it was also present in the search text, so would also require escaping as `\:`.